# Inserting custom fields into new-post.php without using the Custom Fields Template plugin?

Tags: custom-field

I know there are a few plugins (Custom Fields Template seems to be the most popular one) that lets me insert custom fields into the new-post.php template. But I'm wondering if I can add in a few fields without using a plugin -- just as a mock-up. Do I have to go into the core?

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027965/how-to-add-custom-fields-in-wordpress-add-a-new-post-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article will get you there: http://andrewferguson.net/2008/09/26/using-add_meta_box/